# disableSSLCertValidation in ACRA v4.9.2

Tags: android, crash-reports, acra

I am using ACRA v4.9.2 with self signed SSL certificate and I want to disable SSL validation but couldn't find option to disable SSL in ACRA v4.9.2.  Anybody has idea how can I achieve it in ACRA v4.9.2 ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't "disable SSL". Among other things, that would get you banned from the Play Store, if that was part of your intended distribution strategy. Instead, you teach ACRA to recognize your self-signed certificate, [by giving it a custom `KeyStore` that knows about your certificate](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#configuring-a-keystore).

Comment: I will not publish my app to play store and my app will run on local network only and my server generates the SSL certificate dynamically every time I start it so It will be difficult for me give a custom KeyStore

Comment: @KrishnaMeena: If this is only on your local network, there is no point in using an `https` URL. Use an `http` URL. Otherwise, I do not think that you can use ACRA without forking it.

Comment: It is possible to do this without forking ACRA, but you'd have to supply your own HttpSender (you can extend the existing one or copy most of it's code). Note that we will not include code to disable ssl in ACRA, as this would prevent all apps using it from using the play store.